# Organizing a go project that includes codes in other languages

Tags: go

I am currently working on a project that has several parts.  Some of these parts are written entirely in Go, and some are written in other languages including python.  What is the recommended way to organize my project's structure?  I would like all parts to be in one Git repository.  I am familiar with the guidelines outlined in [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), but it doesn't seem right to have python code in the same place as Go code.

Would something like this make sense?

```
myproject
├── go-subproject1/
│   ├── bin/
│   ├── pkg/
│   └── src/
│       ├── bar.go
│       ├── foo.go
│       └── main.go
├── go-subproject2/
│   ├── bin/
│   ├── pkg/
│   └── src/
│       ├── bar.go
│       ├── foo.go
│       └── main.go
└── python-subproject/
    └── src/
        └── com/
            ├── __init__.py
            └── myusername/
                ├── __init__.py
                └── api/
                    ├── __init__.py
                    ├── bar.py
                    └── main.py
```

Comment: With this project layout, it would make a mess out of your `$GOPATH` variable. While it is still possible, it is generally not advised. Though, if you do end up using this type of layout, you may want to look into git submodules.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to give an answer that covers all situations, but the [Vitess MySQL proxy](https://github.com/youtube/vitess/) at Google has subdirectories for the parts in Go, Java, etc. They don't seem to really define 'subprojects' like that even though their app is multiple binaries (maybe they the binaries some packages).

Comment: I think I could solve the `$GOPATH` problem with a one-line shell script in each subproject's root directory that exports the correct path for that?

Comment: Would it be more correct to just make multiple repos and namespace them (i.e. call them `projectname-api`, `projectname-queuer`, etc?

Comment: The Vitess project is very interesting. As you can see from their Makefile they handle the multiple languages well. https://github.com/youtube/vitess/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: Would advise against multiple `GOPATH`s -- better for pieces of your app to live under one workspace, be `go get`able, be able to share code with each other transparently, and for you to have just one environment to manage. For what it's worth, here's someone on that exact topic: http://mwholt.blogspot.com/2014/02/why-i-use-just-one-gopath.html

Comment: Under that `GOPATH` you might put the `package main`s for your binaries under `domain.com/user/proj/cmd/api`, `domain.com/user/proj/cmd/queue`, etc., with most of their guts living as package under `domain.com/user/proj/topic` (or just `domain.com/user/topic` if it's a library you want to treat as an independent product). (`domain.com/user` is a standin for `github.com/username`, but maybe you don't need `/user` where you host your repository) Those are long names names but systematic at least.